# Downvoting when the answers are relevant, but have links to a product I help develop

Tags: discussion, downvotes, self-promotion

I am looking at *[What is too much self-promotion, and where do we draw the line?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66148/what-is-too-much-self-promotion-and-where-do-we-draw-the-line)* and *[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)* as guidance here.

A couple of colleagues and I wrote a few of the answers that are pertinent and answering questions; and added links to a product that I work on (**as a legitimate alternative**) for a developer that might come looking to solve said problem. It seems someone is systematically downvoting these posts and I'm assuming given the lack of explanation that it appears too self-promotional to them?

But it **is** answering the question and a legitimate way to solve that problem is to use a product I work on. I didn't think this was against community guidelines. Can someone shed some light on this?

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56085871/759019
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56085578/759019

Comment: Previously posted on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328040/downvoting-when-the-answers-are-relevant-but-have-links-to-a-product-i-help-deve but was suggested that I move this here.

Comment: Both of the posts you link, read way more like a marketing post, than like a stackoverflow answer.  In both cases a significant portion of the text is clearly a canned marketing blurb.  In my experience, such posts are rarely well received.  You disclosed your affiliation, so they may not get closed as SPAM, but that does not mean that will not get down-voted.

Comment: Interesting.. The content does really answer the question posed. It's unfortunate that it's coming across as a marketing blurb; let me make it more neutral to fit better within the guideline.

Comment: Made some edits, would love more feedback @StephenRauch

Comment: I don’t know anything about that particular topic, so will not vote on any of these questions and answers, but it looks to me that these questions are rather broad. The second question linked has another, older answer that looks to me a totally useless answer, much more of an advertisement than an answer, but that one hasn’t been voted down.

Comment: The questions are broad but interesting enough to point a few beginners in a particular direction. It has zero "marketing content" at this point, so, further downvoting is inexplicable IMO. I wish we had a system where a downvote *required* a reason at least from experienced members.

Comment: It appears that further downvotes are coming from folks who actually do not understand the content of any of those answers. This was meant to call attention to a pattern and get feedback, but it seems to have prompted a downvoting spree here instead.

Comment: That is the Meta effect. Also reading your second link, the first is now deleted, it shows you posted (an attempt at) an answer, followed by a link only marketing excerpt for your product. There is no relevance of your product to the answer you wrote.

Comment: @Luuklag you misunderstand. The screenshots are not of my product at all - they are of AWS Kinesis Analytics, the subject of the question. I just removed the images since that seems to be the source of confusion here. I disagree that there is no relevance to my product to the problem the user is trying to solve.

Comment: I understood completely correct. The first part, screenshots included were the answer to the question. The second half was an over promotedly alternative answer.

Comment: @Luuklag it is literally 2 lines with an explanation and a link. And I think it's entirely relevant to the question too. Please explain more about why that is "overly promoted". Would love to understand what better could be done here. I could have more details, but that runs the risk of being overly promotional, which is entirely why I pared it down to 2 lines.